# Travel to Mexico for I-94 dates extension with a valid L1 visa

Tags: l1-visa

I have valid visa for 3 years but when i came to USA, my passport was expiring in 1 year only. So i got I-94 validity as matching to my passport. Now i have got a new passport so can i travel to mexico by air and come back again and will it give me a new I-94 ?
can i go anytime before current I94 expires ?
What are the various documents required ?
what is the best time to go there ?
I will be travelling from Denver so which place is best to go ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can i travel to mexico by air and come back again and will it give me a new I-94 ?

Yes.

> can i go anytime before current I94 expires ?

Yes.

> What are the various documents required ?

Your passport, your visa, and your valid I-129 petition.

> what is the best time to go there ?

"Best" in what respect?  For this purpose it does not matter when you go, as long as you leave the US before your current I-94 expires.  The major considerations are therefore your personal circumstances and preferences.

> I will be travelling from Denver so which place is best to go ?

Again, for this purpose it does not matter, so it depends on your personal circumstances and preferences.

Comment: Ok so can i also go to San diego and then go to San Ysidro  border and cross the border and come back and get a new I94 ? Is there any chance that they can refuse and what docs shall i carry.

Comment: @ankit3533 the documents you must carry are mentioned above.  There is always a chance that you could be refused entry.